# Ui device wait until button visible

Tags: android, junit, automated-tests, android-espresso

Is it possible to `By` search for an id, for example an id of a button?
I want to have my Ui Device wait until the button is visible. Currently I have

`UiDevice.wait(Until.findObject(By.text("Text on Button")), wait_time).action();`

But searching by text seems to be inconsistent between devices, not sure why. I wanted to test searching by object id since that seems like it would be more consistent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
UiDevice.wait(Until.findObject(By.res("com.example.app:id/button")), wait_time).action();
```

Comment: Will the object be found if it is not Visible or only if it's Visible?

Comment: Had trouble getting package name sometimes so made it consistent with `BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ":id/button"`

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/By.html#res(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String) takes 2 params, the first beign pkg name

Comment: To check the ids and generate this kind of code you can use http://culebra.dtmilano.com/

Comment: Terrible design. Tests are flaky by default, therefore I had to create an extension to avoid writing `wait` every time I want to access an object.